# Validation of manifest versions Office365 addin

Tags: office365, manifest, office-addins, office-js

We are trying to submit our first office addin for outlook to the store but are getting rejected due to Outlook webaccess 2013. We are trying to use the 1.3 api which should not be supported in 2013 but the validation team is still testing for owa 2013.

On this page microsoft clearly states that 1.1 is required for OWA 2013.
http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/tutorial-api-requirement-sets

The comment from the validation team is:
Your add-in is not working in the Outlook 2013 client on Windows 7 with Internet Explorer 11. The user is unable to authenticate to Hogia. After authenticating to O365 and then to Hogia, the authentication pop ups close, but the user is not logged in.

The 404 error is no longer seen in a Fiddler trace, but the user is not logged in to the taskpane, and the add-in is not usable.

If you do not support 2013 SP1 because you are using an API only available in 2016/Online, you must put these apis in the requirements tag in your manifest. If you are not using an API only available in 2016/Online, then you must support 2013 SP1.

Provided below is our anonymous manifest. Any ideas on how to restrict the addin to only 1.3. Is it maybe the xml-namespace that also should be 1.3?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- For more information on using transformations
     see the web.config examples at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=214134. -->

<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
  xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0"
  xsi:type="MailApp">

  <Id>0ada1ef7-1cea-4e3a-b946-a234e777d07b</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Provider</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>sv-SE</DefaultLocale>

  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Name"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="Description"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="url" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="url" />
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="url" />
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>

  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.3" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <!-- These elements support older clients that don't support add-in commands -->
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemEdit">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="url"/>
      </DesktopSettings>
      <TabletSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="url"/>
      </TabletSettings>
      <PhoneSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="url"/>
      </PhoneSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>

  <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Edit" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">

        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <!-- Location of the Functions that UI-less buttons can trigger (ExecuteFunction Actions). -->
          <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />

          <!-- Message Read -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface">
            <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab -->
              <Group id="apptComposeDemoGroup">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="apptComposeFunctionButton">
                  <Label resid="funcComposeButtonLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="funcComposeButtonLabel" />
                    <Description resid="funcComposeSuperTipDescription" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="functionFile" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ButtonCommands to learn how to add more Controls: ExecuteFunction and Menu -->
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
          <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ExtensionPointsCommands to learn how to add more Extension Points: MessageRead, AppointmentOrganizer, AppointmentAttendee -->
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>

    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="url"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="url"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="url"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="url"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="Name"/>
        <bt:String id="funcComposeButtonLabel"  DefaultValue="Name"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="string"/>
        <bt:String id="funcComposeSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="string"/>
        <bt:String id="funcComposeSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="string"/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: I believe you are confusing Outlook Web App 2013 (the on premises version of OWA shipped with Exchange 2013) and Outlook 2013 for Windows. Without seeing the entire validation report I'm not able to give a definitive answer but I believe they are flagging your add-in for not working on Outlook 2013 SP1 for Windows, not for OWA with Exchange 2013.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this might be the case. I provided the entire response from validation above.

Comment: Yeah, the problem was the Outlook 2013 for windows. The problem with the sign in was regarding to a redirect after a correctly recieved token. The browser inside Outlook 2013 for windows had the same url in its address-field so the browser tought that it didnt need to redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that this issue is around OAUTH, I would recommend looking at the [Dialog API](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/officeui). One of the core purposes of this API is to handle scenarios like this.

This assumes you are not interested in targeting Outlook 2013 however. The Dialog API requires Mailbox 1.4 which is only supported in 2016 today. By requiring 1.4 the add-in will not surface on Outlook 2013.

Comment: Is this still relevant? I'm trying to help a customer of ours to get our add-in to work with their Exchange 2013. But when they try to install it it simply says that their Exchange doesn't support Mailbox API 1.3. Here's the message: https://preview.ibb.co/kTbACH/image001.png

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure which versions are supported by Exchange 2013 but I would expect v1.3 to work. Make sure they're updated to the latest CU. I know there were some EWS changes related to Add-ins in CU19 for example.